# Automatically add index.php to end of URL

Tags: .htaccess

When the user visits my site, the URL displayed is http://example.com.

How do I automatically add /index.php to the end of the URL to make it http://example.com/index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DirectoryIndexRedirect` directive

```
DirectoryIndexRedirect on
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. That gives me `Internal Server Error`

Comment: Perhaps your apache version is bellow 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php [R=301,L]
```

But why would you want that?